# how to convert numpy array of arrays into array of matrices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy array of arrays (it's the list of pictures and each picture is flattened and represented as 1x784). I want to get array of matrices (each matrix should be represented as 28x28) how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whatever-your-array-of-arrays-is-called.reshape(-1,28,28)` will reshape.

If that does not yield the correct representation, you'll still be able to figure it out using reshapes, but then for example by looping and reshaping individual array.